# replace quotes in substring (preferably without external dependencies)

Tags: awk, sed

I'm trying to sanitize quotes(`"`) in text file by replacing them with `\"` or an empty string. The replacing must occur in substring delimited by TOKEN placeholders.

Example

```
# input (example.txt):
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with "quotation marks"
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with "another quotation marks"
Line title "C" - TOKEN some "line" TOKEN more "text"
Random "line"


# result (example.txt)
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with \"quotation marks\"
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with \"another quotation marks\"
Line title "C" - TOKEN some \"line\" TOKEN more "text"
Random "line"


# Another option
# result (example.txt)
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with quotation marks
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with another quotation marks
Line title "C" - TOKEN some line TOKEN more "text"
Random "line"
```

Preferably without external dependencies(i.e Python,JS) on Linux, so probably `sed, awk, bash` are best

PS - What I've tried so far is:

```
sed -iE "s/TOKEN(.+)(\")(.+).*\TOKEN\1\3/g" /tmp/test
```

But it handles only a single replacement per line

**EDIT**:
(sorry about late addition after many answers)

- TOKEN is a a delimiter - Added Line title "C" to the example
- No replacement should occur on line without TOKEN - Added Random "line"

Comment: Note that your attempt has errors. It should be `sed -i -E "s/TOKEN(.+)(\")(.+).*/TOKEN\1\3/g"` and can be simplified to `sed -i -E 's/(TOKEN.+)"(.+)/\1\2/g'`

Comment: *without external dependencies(i.e Python,JS) on Linux* I am not sure how do you define *external* here, but if anything which did came with OS (i.e. was not installed separately) then your Linux OS might already have `python` available. Do `python --version` to check, if it did output python (version number) then you have it.

Comment: I take "external" as meaning "not a mandatory Unix tool" so sed, awk, grep but not perl, python ruby for example.

Comment: Can `TOKEN` appear anywhere else on the line? If so should the separator be the first or last occurrence of `TOKEN`? Is `TOKEN` in your example a placeholder for a string or a character (and if so which) or literally the word `TOKEN`?

Comment: Can lines with `"`s but without `TOKEN` appear in the input?

Comment: @EdMorton , you right - although Perl looks also pretty omnipresent - so don't sure whether to include it.

TOKEN is a placeholder - actual string can vary.
Multiple occurrences - see edit

Comment: Perl is very common, but we do get questions where only the mandatory POSIX toolset is available and in that case it'd exclude perl. (I also spent 30 years working on just such a platform which is probably why I never learned any perl!). You didn't answer - can you or can you not or not have lines that do not contain any `TOKEN`.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes it's possible. No substitution in this case

Comment: You should add that case to your sample input/output then. Also please consolidate your examples into 1 sample input and 1 expected output blocks so we can just copy/paste that to test with and don't need to have multiple test input/output files.

Comment: You're righ @EdMorton - Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that:

1. you want `TOKEN` treated as a regular expression (or if not will escape metachars in advance of using it),
2. a line where `TOKEN` doesn't occur should be left unchanged, and
3. `TOKEN` matches even if it's in the middle of another string

then using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '
match($0,/TOKEN.*TOKEN/) || match($0,/TOKEN.*/) {
    tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    gsub(/"/, "\\\"", tgt)
    $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) tgt substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1' example.txt
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with \"quotation marks\"
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with \"another quotation marks\"
Line title "C" - TOKEN some \"line\" TOKEN more "text"
Random "line"
```

Comment: Thanks @ed. Accepted for POSIXness and for supporting 2 TOKEN occurences.

Would appreciate if you jot a short explanation for non-awk adepts among us.

Comment: @Vano You're welcome. I think it's very obvious what the code is doing and it doesn't need any explanation (maybe after a glance at the awk man page), but if you have any specific questions please do feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Removing all double quotation marks after `TOKEN` substring with `sed` can be done with

```sh
sed -i -E ':A; s/(TOKEN[^"]*)"/\1/g; tA' /tmp/test
```

Replacing `"` with `\"` after `TOKEN` is also possible:

```sh
sed -i -E ':A; s/(TOKEN[^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"]*)*)"/\1\\"/g; tA' /tmp/test
```

*Details*:

- `:A` - sets a label `A`
- `s/(TOKEN[^"]*)"/\1/g` - finds all occurrences of `TOKEN`, zero or more chars other thab `"` (captured into Group 1) and then matches a `"`, and replaces the match with Group 1  value (the version with `[^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"]*)*` matches all escaped chars together with any chars other than double quotation marks, and `\1\\"` replacement puts back Group 1 value + an escaped `"`)
- `tA` - goes back to label `A` upon successful replacement.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/65nDyM):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with "quotation marks"'
sed -E ':A; s/(TOKEN[^"]*)"/\1/g; tA' <<< "$s"
# => Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with quotation marks
sed -E ':A; s/(TOKEN[^\\"]*(\\.[^\\"]*)*)"/\1\\"/g; tA' <<< "$s"
# => Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with \"quotation marks\"
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe 's/TOKEN\K(.*)/$1 =~ s|"|\\"|gr/e' -- example.txt
```

It's a substitution inside a substitution.

The outer substitution looks like this:

```
s/TOKEN\K(.*)/.../e
```

Which replaces everything after TOKEN with the `...` part. The `/e` means the `...` part is evaluated as code.

The replacement code is `$1 =~ s|"|\\"|gr`. It substitutes all `"` with `\"` in the contents of `$1`, i.e. the part matched by the outer substitution, and returns the result (that's what the `/r` does).

To remove the double quotes instead of escaping, just delete the `\\"` part.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `perl` solution. This deletes all double quotes only if `TOKEN` doesn't occur later in the input line. Use `perl -i -pe` for in-place modification.

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/"(?!.*TOKEN)//g' ip.txt
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with quotation marks
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with another quotation marks
```

If there can be lines with double quotes not containing `TOKEN` and such quotes shouldn't be changed, use `perl -pe 's/"(?!.*TOKEN)//g if /TOKEN/'`

Here's an `awk` solution. Input is split using `TOKEN` as the field delimiters and then the substitution is perfomed on the second field. Lines not containing `TOKEN` won't be modified.

```sh
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="TOKEN"} {gsub(/"/, "", $2)} 1' ip.txt
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with quotation marks
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with another quotation marks
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide and conquer in `sed` -

```
$: sed '/TOKEN/{ h; s/TOKEN.*//; x; s/^.*TOKEN//; s/"/\\"/g; H; x; s/\n/TOKEN/; }' file
# input (example.txt):
Line title "A" - TOKEN some line with \"quotation marks\"
Line title "B" - TOKEN some line with \"another quotation marks\"
```

Explanation:

`/TOKEN/{ ...}` - This acts only on lines with the TOKEN
`h;` - this places a copy of the line in the `h`old buffer
`s/TOKEN.*//;` - this removes from TOKEN through the end of the pattern buffer copy
`x;` - this e`x`changes the pattern and hold buffers, placing the abbreviated beginning in the hold buffer and the complete record in the pattern buffer
`s/^.*TOKEN//;` - eliminate the part you do NOT want changed from the pattern buffer copy
`s/"/\\"/g;` - backslash-quote the double-quotes characters remaining in the pattern buffer copy; use `s/"//g` to just remove them
`H;` this *appends* a newline to the hold buffer, then adds the pattern buffer copy as another line in the hold buffer
`x;` - this switched the entire hold buffer back to the pattern buffer
`s/\n/TOKEN/;` - this replaces the newline with TOKEN

In English:

1. make a copy.
2. chop the part you plan to edit off the original.
3. swap to save the original *beginning*.
4. chop the beginning off the part you plan to edit.
5. backslash or remove the quotes in the part you want edited.
6. stack the edited end onto the original beginning.
7. swap them back in and paste them back onto one line with the TOKEN between.

Comment: Any chance of making it compatible with the latest Edit to the question?